# Constantly cycling string

Tags: javascript

What would an efficient method of making a constantly cycling string in PHP?

Im trying to make it so that string $r cycles between these characters:

-

\

|

/

so that it looks as if it were animated when it's echoed. I tried making an infinite loop like this:

```
while(1) {
    $r = "-";
    $r = "\";
    $r = "|";
    $r = "/";
}
```

but the page wouldn't load, so I would assume that it wouldn't load because it wont load any content until the loop is finished.

Comment: This should be done client-side, not in PHP.

Comment: So would you suggest I do it in Javascript?

Comment: there are many pretty animated loading gif's, which would look a lot less chessey. and even an app to make your own: http://ajaxload.info/

Comment: I would rather not use an animated GIF, I'd prefer it to be text

Comment: @DrewPierce since when do proven technologies win over "cool techs" like AJAX? :P  Seriously, ColeJohnson - ajax means Asynchronous Javascript and XML - there's no need for that in this problem. Basic Javascript will do the job if AlphaDelta really wants to use characters instead of an animated gif.

Comment: ok, it will look cheap and nasty, but still its a client side issue

Comment: i can believe we are even talking about this

Answer (score 5):

`while(1)` is just going to lock up the browser. This needs to be done in javascript, but even then you are still going to run into troubles.

Comment: So how could I achieve this in Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

See this answer of mine: [javascript spinner for grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218994/javascript-spinner-for-grails/12219277#12219277)

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    var spinner = document.getElementById("spinner_container")​​​​;
    spinner.anim_mode = 0;
    var animation = ["|", "/", "–", "\\"]
    var spin = function() {
        spinner.anim_mode = (spinner.anim_mode + 1) % animation.length;
        spinner.innerHTML = animation[spinner.anim_mode];
    };
    spin();
    setInterval(spin, 100);
};​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dGL8X/

Comment: Click several times on the button for extra fun! ;)

Comment: stop clicking! you are tearing a whole in the fabric of space and time!

Answer (score 0):

This CAN be done in php, but it makes no sense to do so.

You just need to `echo $r;` and turn on output buffering. You'd have to echo some Javascript to clear what's already on the screen, then echo the new character. But it's really a bad idea. I've seen loading bars done like this, though, there used to be (still is?) a library based on it.

Comment: prove it, show the code, its got to spin, no page refreshing :-)

Comment: I was about to take you up on that challenge 'till I spent 20 minutes re-configuring nginx to allow incremental buffering. I swear it used to be easier than this! Then again I used to be doing this on Windows with xampp.. hmm, times have changed. Take a look at http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php - this actually is really easy to do with the right setup.